# Barra de progreso

Tags: python

Hay alguna manera de hacer una barra de progreso en python ? O alguna librería?. 
Por ejm: si tengo una función que a su vez se compone de otras funciones o un ciclo for que deba iterar en una lista inmesa. Me gustaría mostrarle al usuario cuanto es el tiempo restante.alguna idea?

Answer (score 1):

Usa el paquete [progress](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/progress).

```
from progress.bar import Bar

bar = Bar('Processing', max=20)
for i in range(20):
    # Do some work
    bar.next()
bar.finish()
```

Para instalarlo usa pip: `pip install progress`

Answer (score 1):

Si no querés instalar nada. Una buena implementación para python 2 es:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Print iterations progress
def print_progress(iteration, total, prefix='', suffix='', decimals=1, bar_length=100):
    """
    Call in a loop to create terminal progress bar
    @params:
        iteration   - Required  : current iteration (Int)
        total       - Required  : total iterations (Int)
        prefix      - Optional  : prefix string (Str)
        suffix      - Optional  : suffix string (Str)
        decimals    - Optional  : positive number of decimals in percent complete (Int)
        bar_length  - Optional  : character length of bar (Int)
    """
    str_format = "{0:." + str(decimals) + "f}"
    percents = str_format.format(100 * (iteration / float(total)))
    filled_length = int(round(bar_length * iteration / float(total)))
    bar = '█' * filled_length + '-' * (bar_length - filled_length)

    sys.stdout.write('\r%s |%s| %s%s %s' % (prefix, bar, percents, '%', suffix)),

    if iteration == total:
        sys.stdout.write('\n')
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

La podés encontrar en el siguiente link: https://gist.github.com/aubricus/f91fb55dc6ba5557fbab06119420dd6a

Espero que te sirva!